# cant understand what is "Where T:" in C#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
 public class TwitterResponse<T>
        where T : Core.ITwitterObject
    {
       // all properties and methods here
    }
```

Can someone explain me what is this in simple terms ?  what is "where T :Core.ITwitterObject " part here ? Have seen this in Twitterizer source code. Any examples to better understand this ?

Comment: Yep, just remove the `where T :` line and see what the compiler complains about :) -- **[Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that `T` must implement interface `Core.ITwitterObject`.

If you pass to the generic a type `T` not implementing this interface, a compile-time error occurs.

This condition allows the compiler to call the functions which are declared in `Core.ITwitterObject` on instances of `T`.

Look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Example:

```
interface IFoo { void Perform(); }

class FooList<T> where T : IFoo
{
    List<T> foos;
    ...
    void PerformForAll()
    {
        foreach (T foo in foos)
            foo.Perform(); // this line compiles because the compiler knows
                           // that T implements IFoo
    }
}
```

This has an advantage over the customary

```
interface IFoo { void Perform(); }

class FooList
{
    List<IFoo> foos;
    ...
    void PerformForAll()
    {
        foreach (IFoo foo in foos)
            foo.Perform();
    }
    // added example method
    IFoo First { get { return foos[0]; } }
}
```

because the methods like `First` would be more type-safe, you won't need to downcast from `IFoo` to `SomeRandomFooImpl`.

Answer (score 2):

it is a constrain on the generic type T. It means T can only be a `Core.ITwitterObject` type

Comment: so in simple terms its just


     public class TwitterResponse : Core.ITwitterObject 

which means class TwitterResponse  should implement interface ITwitterObject.

why is it then written as `<T>` , any advantage ?

Comment: that's to make sure you don't use any other object exept those that implement this interface.Reason? let's suppose the class has a method that call a method on the ITwitterObject. Using the constrain it forces you to pass an object that implements that interface so the code will be executed

Comment: `<T>` is your generic placeholder, so just like you can say `List<int>' or '`List<string>` you can call the List functions on either object, so in this case you would have `TwitterResponse<CustomTwitterResponse>` where `CustomTwitterResponse` must implement Core.ITwitterObject.

Comment: @Anil: no, `TwitterResponse` doesn't need to implement `Core.ITwitterObject`. Only `T` has to.

Answer (score 2):

It's a constraint for generics, so the constraint says it must implement Core.ITwitterObject.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `where` keyword specifies what type(s) can be represented by the `T` in the generic class definition. In this case it means that only ITwitterObject (presumably an interface) can be represented, i.e. that you can only use objects that implement the ITwitterObject interface.

There's a pretty clear [explanation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx). Key excerpt:

> When you define a generic class, you can apply restrictions to the
>   kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it
>   instantiates your class. If client code attempts to instantiate your
>   class with a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result is a
>   compile-time error. These restrictions are called constraints.
>   Constraints are specified using the where contextual keyword.